# Can I play SimCity 4 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, simcity-4

Can I play SimCity 4 on Windows 7 (64 bit)?

I want to know before buying it.

Comment: Slight English nit-pick but in this case you should use "can" instead of "may" (unless you really are asking our permission to play SimCity 4 on Windows 7 rather than asking about the ability to play SimCity 4 on Windows 7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been playing SimCity 4 (Deluxe Edition) on Windows 7 64-bit for a few weeks now and it's been relatively problem-free. I did have a problem running the game full screen after installing the [update available from EA](http://simcity.ea.com/update/index_update.php?product=EP1&x=22&y=7), but right-clicking the shortcut, going to *Properties* → *Compatibility*, and checking the *Disable desktop composition* option resolved that issue.

Outside of that, the game has run fine. I haven't experienced the Alt+Tab issue that [Buss described](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/can-i-play-simcity-4-on-windows7/9986#9986), so I'm unsure what may have caused that. I did install the game from the original CD, so the SC4 + Steam might be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.simprograms.com/simcity/simcity-4/simcity-4-system-requirements/) lists the requirements as:

> **OS**: Windows Vista/XP/ME/2000/98 (Windows 95/NT not supported)

So I would expect that it would run under Windows 7. However, there are a number of posts on other forums indicating problems. Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows? Most of the problems do seem to relate to 64-bit Windows.

The site also has link to a [requirements tester](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/referrer/srtest) so you check that too.

I'd suggest that if you are experiencing problems you could always run in XP compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

I run it on a Windows 7 (32-bit).

The only thing that doesn't work is alt+tab (the game crashes), but I'm not sure if this is a SC4 or a SC4 + Steam problem.

Comment: I just purchased the Steam edition of SC4 to replace my old disc version... I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, and I haven't crashed the game by alt-tabbing... I did get a weird graphic glitch once, but that cleared when I alt-tabbed out and back in again.